# How to break the at end of line inside<td> in <table> using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table as:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var enteredText = document.getElementById("textArea").value;

 var numberOfLineBreaks = (enteredText.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
 var characterCount = enteredText.length + numberOfLineBreaks;

 alert('Number of breaks:  ' + numberOfLineBreaks);
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tapshil" id="" border="2px" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th> <font face="preeti">l;=g+=</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> k|=b=g</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> ldlt</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> eG;f/ dx;'n tyf hl/jfgf</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> cGtMz'Ns</font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> d"=c=s/ </font></th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf dx;'n</font> </th>
         <th><font face="preeti"> hDdf  </font> </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <!-- put loop here -->
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>11
            1212231
         </td>
         <td id="textArea">भैरवा भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 बिराटनगर भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
         </td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>15</td>
         <td id="totalOfAll">36</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

In my UI it is appearing as:

[image]

In my table there is one data coming in  as:

```
 <td id="textArea">भैरवा भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01 बिराटनगर भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
             </td>
```

I want to split after `भैरवा भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01` and bring  `बिराटनगर भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01` into new line but it is not coming.IN my UI it is coming in straight line. How can i break it into new line? I want my output be like:

```
 <td id="textArea">भैरवा भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
                   बिराटनगर भन्सार  2070-01-01 2072-01-01
   </td>
```

Comment: i have edited the title sorry

Comment: _“but it is not coming”_ - where should it be coming from? The JS code you have shown seems to count existing line breaks only, so what exactly did you expect to happen now based on that …?

Comment: And btw., merely giving a random element an id `textarea`, doesn’t make it an actual `textarea` element. You do not have a textarea here, but a table cell - so there is no `value` property you could read to get the content. Go research how to access the text content of a table cell the right way.

Comment: You could use the CSS word-break property to break the word.

Comment: You cannot use `document.getElementById("textArea").value` on a `<td>` as it doesn't really have a value. You can use it on form fields. To get the HTML inside <`td>`, use `document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML`

Comment: add you loop code here. I believe it shouldn't be hard coded value. And you cannot have same id multiple times your code will not work instead use class.

Comment: why aren't you just adding the line break into what ever is rendering this output? that seems the easiest solution rather than trying to hack the rendering using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to format the text using Javascript/JQuery, but to format it while it is rendered.

Assuming based on your example that, you have a fixed format (shown below) of the text displayed in your `<td>` tag, you can parse the text with space (' ') and format it as per your display requirements.

```
Fixed format: firstName lastName Date1 Date2 firstName lastName Date1 Date2 ...
```

Solution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var enteredText = $("#textArea").html(); //Get the InnerHTML

        var NumOfOccurrences = (enteredText.match(/\s/g) || []).length; //All the occurrences of space (' ')
        var n = 3; //Initial occurrence
        while(n <= NumOfOccurrences) {
            enteredText = enteredText.replace(RegExp("^(?:.*? ){" + n + "}"), function(val){return val.replace(RegExp(' ' + "$"), "<br>")}); //Replace the occurrence
            n = n+ 2; //Increment by 2 to determine next occurrence
        }
        $("#textArea").html(enteredText); //Replace the InnerHTML
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The output needs to be भैरवा भन्सार 2070-01-01 2072-01-01 at one line and at another line  बिराटनगर भन्सार 2070-01-012072-01-01 format is  : text date date newline text date date

Comment: if u can help me help me please

Comment: it is not coming as i mentioned :(

Comment: Whats the issue you are seeing? I tried it and it worked for me. Not with `Hindi` names, but with `English` names.

Comment: its ok bro i managed to do it you need to make n=5 and n=n+5 thank you